# Scripts and Styles not loading in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a `wordpress` local installation and I am trying to load scripts and styles with `wp_enqueue` but none of these are working, the front-end is not capturing any of the files,

Here is the code:

```
<?php
function all_the_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/bootstrap.css' );
  wp_enqueue_style( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/custom.css' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap.bundle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootstrap.bundle.js' , array ( 'jquery' ) );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/custom-scripts.js', array ( 'jquery' ) ); 
}   
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'all_the_scripts' );
?>
```

I have double checked everything, all the files are in the correct locations and all required arguments are given, but still no result.

I tried `wp_register_script` but they say that it is optional and not needed

Comment: in which file you write this code ? function.php or somewhere else ?

Answer (score 2):

Use 
 `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`

instead of

`get_template_directory_uri()`

The `get_template_directory_uri()` reference to the parent theme if you're developing **Child Themes**, and [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) returns the **URI** of the current theme.